# Can't use parseInt for images - Android

Tags: android, integer, android-image, imagesource, parseint

I have a problem with putting different images in a list.
I created a custom list and everything worked fine, except the images issue.
My issue is with these line -

```
Integer p = Integer.parseInt("R.drawable.absolut");
holder.icon.setImageResource(p);
```

In the log I see the following error-

03-03 08:16:07.121: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25486): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'R.drawable.absolut' as integer

What could cause this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse int intended for parsing strings like "0", "100" etc and has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve. You have to use the drawable id directly:

```
holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

If for whatever reason you can't use the constant, correct way to get the drawable id would be:

```
Context context = getContext(); //obtain a context
int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

But that's not a good practice at all and idicates that you have problems with your app design.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of photos, and I don't want to manually put them in an array. Is there a better way to do that,perhaps using their names and get the ID that way?

Comment: @tofira well in that case use the getIdentifier method as I described.

Comment: +1 Nice One.This helped me in case where my image names comes from database.